# Problema en insert MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Quiero insertar en una tabla pasandole los valores en un `select` interno en el `insert`, pero no me está funcionando:

```
INSERT INTO `atrazados`(`id`, `tiro`, `fecha`, `atrasado`) 
VALUES(SELECT `tirada`,MAX(`fecha`) ,DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(),MAX(`fecha`))  FROM  `tiradas` WHERE `tirada`=1)
```

Este es el código si alguien me pudiera ayudar

Answer (score 1):

Quítale el `VALUES (` y déjalo así

```
INSERT INTO `atrazados`(`tiro`, `fecha`, `atrasado`) 
SELECT `tirada`,MAX(`fecha`) ,DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(),MAX(`fecha`))  
FROM  `tiradas` 
WHERE `tirada`=1
```

Entendiendo que el campo `id` es autonumérico.

Comment: Si el ID es auto increment

Comment: Si Gracias me funcionó así